# Perl expression to match multi-line

Tags: regex, perl, verilog

I am trying extract all name* from following set of pattern.

```
name1 name2 ( .name3 ( name4 ) , .name5 ( name6 ) , ..... , .nameM ( nameN ) )
```

In above line spaces and new line character can be there interchangeably. 
So this pattern can extend for multiple lines.
N can be of any length for each pattern.

This is verilog syntax and denotes module,instance and port names.

I need an regular expression to get this.

Is there a easy way to do this other than first joining all lines first.

name* is just a place holder. It can be *a-zA-Z0-9_*

Sample file i am using

```
module1 instance1 (
.A(B) ,.C(D))
```

Piece of code where i get A in $1 and B in $2. I am unable to get C and D.

```
while(<ORIG>)
{
  if($_ =~ m/\.(.*?)\((.*?)\)/g) 
  { 
    print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4";
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at [`Verilog::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Verilog::Parser)?

Comment: `name\d+` with a `g` flag ????????????/

Comment: name is just a placeholder It can be a-zA-Z0-9_

Comment: `my @matches = $string =~ /(\w+)/g` ?

Comment: Show us a what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is first extract the entire instance declaration. Then the trick is the extract the port list as one string.

`\s*\n*\s*\.\w+\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\)\s*\n*\s*,?` will match any port, however we don't want to flood the buffer list (we don't event know the number) so we should use `(?:...)` around it. Then sample the ports together with `((?:...)+)` resulting with `((?:\s*\n*\s*\.\w+\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\)\s*\n*\s*,?)+)`

Extract from a file:

```
$dosample = 0;
$sample = "";
while (my $line = <ORIG>)
{
    if ( $line =~ m/^\s*(\w+)\s+\w+\s*\(/) {
        if ( $1 ne "module" ) {
            $dosample = 1;
            $sample = "";
        }
    }
    if ($dosample == 1) {
        $sample .= $line;
        if ( $line =~ m/\)\s*;/ ) {
            # instance declaration sampled, now extract
            @names = &extractNames($sample);
            # cleanup
            $sample = "";
            $dosample = 0;
            printf "%s\n", join(", ", @names);
        }
    }
}

sub extractNames {
    my $toParse = shift;
    if ( $toParse =~ m/(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s*\(((?:\s*\n*\s*\.\w+\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\)\s*\n*\s*,?)+)\s*\)/ )
    {
        ($moduleName,$instName,$portlist_string) = ($1,$2,$3);
        $portlist_string =~ s/[\n\s]//g; # get rid of spaces and newlines
        $portlist_string =~ s/\(/,/g; # swap opening parenthesis with comas
        $portlist_string =~ s/[\.\)]//g; # get rid of periods and closing parenthesis
        @portlist = split( ",", $portlist_string); # array of .name(name)
        return ($moduleName,$instName,@portlist);
    }
    else {
        die "bad match:\n\n$_\n\n";
    }
}
```

Input file:

```
module dut ( A, B,
 C, D);


module1 instance1 (
.A(B) ,.C(D));

module2 inst2 ( .A ( B ) , .B ( B ) ,       .M ( N ) );

module3 inst3 ( .n3 ( B ) , .n5 ( D ),
.M ( N ), 



.Y( Z) )  ;

endmodule
```

Outputs:

```
module1, instance1, A, B, C, D
module2, inst2, A, B, B, B, M, N
module3, inst3, n3, B, n5, D, M, N, Y, Z
```

Comment: Except for couple of corner_conditions it works completely fine. 1) Module and instance being in separate line and 2) Port names having [number]. I added minor hacks here and there to get through.

Comment: what kind of corner case?